# Og:image not showing in FB debugger but link is ok

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a very very strange problem. I use a WordPress website to publish a picture every day, and of course, I want to publish it on my facebook page.

I've tried with Open Graph informations from Yoast, or from Jetpack and both but the problem is the same : no picture to show on social networks! Not a good thing for pictures based website ;-)

I've tried Open Graph debugger and when I look at this, I have a good link to my image on og:image property... but the picture doesn't display. It's a transparent picture to click that open the good image in a new link, but can't publish it on social networks.

You can try with this adress : http://social.1max2peche.com/belle-boule-de-mucus/

Comment: Is there some chance that FB is not able to see the image for some sort of "remote linking denied" kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Put in the image URL directly (in the browser): http://www.1max2peche.com/design/magazine-peche-1max2peche-logo.png

Happens to at least 2 out of 3 images in the og:image tags, and it may be the problem. Also take a look at the image specifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

You see that it redirects, so of course Facebook cannot get it. Make sure to check out your rewrite stuff.